# How to open apps on startup only on a particular time

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-task-scheduler

Right now, Microsoft Teams open whenever I open my Laptop. But the thing is — I only need teams during 7 AM to 12 PM. And if you know, Teams is very Resource-consuming and causes my old laptop to hang. So, I wanted to configure it such that Teams opens on startup only when I open my laptop between 7 AM - 12 PM. Is this possible? Possibly using task scheduler?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than starting Teams on startup, you can write a small script that first checks the time, and then starts the application.

Here's an example PowerShell script. Save it with a `.ps1` file extension and place a shortcut to it in your startup folder

```
# Get the hour in 24h format
[int]$hour = Get-Date -Format "HH"

# Start teams only between 7 and 12 in the morning
if ($hour -gt 7 -and $hour -le 12) 
{
    Start-Process $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Teams\Current\Teams.exe
}
```

A DOS batch file would look something like this. Note that the `%time%` variable is culture dependent, so I'm not sure if this works with a 12 hour time format. A better way would be to use `wmic` to get the time. There are many questions about that already.

```
for /f "delims=:" %%x in ("%time%") do set hour=%%x

if %hour% GEQ 7 (
    if %hour% LSS 12 (
        %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Teams\Current\Teams.exe
    )
)
```

Comment: This answer works!. But, it requires us to change Powershell's execution policy to Unrestricted — which is a security threat. Can it be done via a batch file?

Comment: Yes, I added a sample batch file.

Answer (score 0):

> So, I wanted to configure it such that Teams opens on startup only
> when I open my laptop between 7 AM - 12 PM. Is this possible?

Instead of trying to manage this, set Teams to NOT start when Windows starts.   Do that in Teams or in Task Manager Startup tab.

Now open Teams on Demand.

I do this with Teams, Zoom and Skype. Works fine.

Comment: I know I can do that, too. But I thought if it could happen automatically, it would have been better.

Comment: I have been using these apps for some long time. Starting Automatically is not simply controlled in terms of time or starting relative to other apps.  So starting on Demand is just easier overall.